How to study algebraic topology?
I'm graduate student in second semester
Since the class uses Hatcher's book, I read it and tried to solve exercises, But it's too hard for me.
The reason first is that it's hard to read. I'm reading it with second half of munkres's topology, and I think I understood quite a few theorems and proofs of fundamental groups, vamkampen thm, covering space, etc. Munkres' book is good to read for me, but Allen Hatcher's book is not. Notion's of Cell complex, operations on spaces, proofs and examples of vamkampen's thm and exercises are not intuitive to me.
And second difficulty is that it's hard to solve exercises. Professor, ta explain roughly and use their intuition freely to explain or solve thms, pf, problems.
It's the second most difficult for me, which the first was Rudin's pma for the first time to learn undergraduate analysis.
My favorite book is stein series 1,2,3 and Rudin Rca. I think Hatcher's book has quite different style with other books like Hungerfold, Rudin, or ect. In honest, Lee was hard for me, too and I'm gonna read again in December to prepare Qualifying exam. I think I can study Lee again but I don't have confidence reading Hatcher
There's many recommendations in this site, and I hope to read another book and skip Hatcher's book. I want to know someone's opionion that whether I'm not qualified to study graduate course, or just dismatch of style, or try Hatcher after reading other books, or any recommendations. Please comment freely.

I had pretty much the same experience. Sadly, most courses on algebraic topology are extremely handwavy, especially those that follow Hatcher's book. It's not just non formal proofs, this book doesn't even contain formal definitions of some important terms. I also strongly prefer Munkres's style. His "topology" book is indeed a great source to learn about the fundamental group. (it contains almost all the results from Hatcher, but with actual formal proofs) Then he also has a book called "elements of algebraic topology" which is about homology and cohomology. (to be continued)

This second book I've mentioned is also very rigorous, but it also does contain geometric ideas. It is certainly possible to have both. That being said, the books can only help you to self study. They might not help you with the course. If the course uses Hatcher's book then it might also contain lots of examples and exercises from there. About the exercises, it shouldn't be a problem that they are difficult, math shouldn't be easy. My problem was that many exercises in Hatcher are by nature not supposed to be solved formally, but rather by drawing pictures.

I also found Hatcher difficult, but just started on Massey and have enjoyed it more.

Dont give up my friend you can do it!

Algebraic topology can be difficult, but it’s also incredibly exciting! My advice is that if you feel this topic could be something that you are interested in, and you feel that there’s something elegant there, don’t give up. Rather, stay motivated and look for the explainations which make sense to you.
Let me propose a few resources to you which you may find helpful. My disclaimer being that these choices likely reflect the ways in which my brain thinks - usually this is wanting a very visual or motivating example, and slowly adding formalism after the foundations are set. I won’t be offended if you’re not a fan of these - pick and choose from them as you please!
Videos: For quite visual topics as these, videos as a starting point can be incredibly useful. My recommendations are the lecture series by Insights into Mathematics(https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=Ap2c1dPyIVo), the lecture series by Math by Andrew’s University (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kCTpfqRJ2kk), and the series by Richard Borcherds (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4f-lk9CMz8).
Lecture Notes: After you have a feel for the topic, with visualisations in mind, lecture notes can be useful as a step up, adding some formalism, but not in such a dense manner as a textbook. One of my favourites is these outstanding introductory notes, they’re very aesthetic too: https://loeh.app.uni-regensburg.de/teaching/topologie1_ws1819/lecture_notes.pdf. In addition these slightly more comprehensive notes: https://people.math.wisc.edu/~lmaxim/topbookf.pdf#page14.
Textbooks: If you’re having trouble with Hatcher because it’s too tricky - I cannot recommend ‘A First Course in Algebraic Topology’ by Kosniowoski enough. It’s a great stepping stone to understanding textbooks like Hatcher.
Let me say that algebraic topology is in no way easy. It combines two subjects together in a beautiful fusion. The only difficulty is that these two subjects we fuse together are difficult in their own right. Don’t be scared by this, because this is mathematics. It’s not supposed to be! Also don’t think that you’re incapable of studying it. Instead find what works for you - maybe that’s a more homotopy perspective, or maybe it’s a more homology perspective.
Draw pictures. Always think of the big picture.
Good luck!
